# Even or Odd String Check

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a program that checks whether the input **string** is even or odd and I keep getting errors I can't figure out why.

> (i = odd, ii = even, iii = odd, iiii = even)  and so on.

I try

```
<?php
    //checking even and odd
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo "<input type='text' name='val'>\n";
    echo "<button type='submit' name='submit'>Check</button>\n";
    echo "</form>";

    $val = 0;
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["val"])) {
        $Err = "<span style ='color: red;'>Required.</span>";
        echo $Err;
        die();
      } else {
          $val = $_POST["val"];
      }


    $even = ($val % 2 == 0);
    $odd = ($val % 2 != 0);
    if ($val > 0){
    if($even){
        echo "Sting is even.";
    } else {
        echo "Sting is odd.";
    }
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please, specify what errors you are getting.

Comment: $value = 10;
if($value%2){
  echo '$value is odd';
}else{
  echo '$value is even';
}

Comment: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\NovemberCircuits\zoo\index.php on line 19

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\NovemberCircuits\zoo\index.php on line 20

Comment: If you are entering something like `iii` then you will need to convert it (to 3) before processing it

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: No, Still hasn't gotten it.
In your solution, it's numeric check and I'm talking about string.

Comment: I was hoping if I could convert every thing the user typed in the text box as a string an then check it length whether or not it's Odd string or Even.

Comment: That makes no sense, try to explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

You can't divide a string, you need to check the length.  Based on your examples of `i`, `ii`, `iii`, `iiii` etc:

```
if(strlen($val) % 2 == 0) {
    //even
} else {
    //odd
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```php
<?php
$val = "10";

if (is_numeric($val)){
  if($val % 2 == 0){
        echo "Even";
    }
    else{
        echo "Odd";
    }
}
else {
  echo "Invalid number";
}
?>
```

Here, `is_numeric($val)` checks if the input is a valid number and not a string. 
This will avoid **Warning: A non-numeric value encountered**

You should further handle the cases where the input is a **negative number** or a **floating-point** number.